# I can't import the styles.scss file from angular-notifier into my project

Tags: angular

I can't import the styles.scss file from angular-notifier into my project.

Here is my error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError:
Can't find stylesheet to import. ╷ 10 │ @import" ~/angular-notifier/styles.scss"; │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ╵ src/styles.scss 10:8 root stylesheet

ERROR in ./src/styles.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js): HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. ╷ 10 │ @import" ~/angular-notifier/styles.scss"; │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ╵ src/styles.scss 10:8 root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Angular 13, it won't resolve ~ for some reason

If you change import to `@import "node_modules/angular-notifier/styles";` it will work

Also you can try `@import "~angular-notifier/styles";`, it should work, but I haven't tested it

Comment: The first solution, adding "node_modules/" instead of "~" worked for me. The second didn't. However, this is not very nice. Does somebody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

`@import "angular-notifier/styles";` works for angular-notifier 7.

Comment: Could you please list the angular version? Because currently I use to catch the current issue:
_Error: Package path ./styles is not exported from package C:\Users\xxx\VSCodeProjects\demo-dashboard\node_modules\angular-notifier (see exports field in C:\Users\xxx\VSCodeProjects\demo-dashboard\node_modules\angular-notifier\package.json)_. I've angular-notifier **14** and not 7, with angular **16**.